# How to implicitly call and override javascript function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

Hi i am trying to make a skeleton for my Node Web app, and i am trying to implicitly "plant" an init() method inside every endpoint, it goes like this

This is how i call my end point

```js
routers.get('/user/signin', UserSignin.init)
```

This fires up init() method inside this class

```js
export default class Signin extends BaseRoutes {

    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    static init(req, res) {

        (async () => {



        })().catch(e => setImmediate(() => {
            console.log(e)
        }))
    }

}
```

Notice that i still need to call init in `UserSignin.init`, what i am trying to achieve is to implicitly call init() method (and inherit the parameter `req,res` and override it in every call so that it runs asynchronously implicitly, is it possible to abstract it?

I tried to execute `init()` inside constructur but then its still explicitly called in every endpoint classes.

To summary my questions :

1. How to abstract `init()` method so that every endpoint doesn't have to call it explicitly.
2. How to override `init()` method so that it runs asyncrhonously by default.

Comment: What is `BaseRoutes`, how is that `SignIn` class used elsewhere? From what you posted, it shouldn't be a `class` at all.

Comment: What is `routers.get`, what framework are you using? Is it capable of working with promises?

Comment: What exactly do you understand by "*so that it runs asynchronously*"?

Comment: bet you're actually looking for middleware -> https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: @Bergi i think it has nothing to do with `BaseRoutes`, sorry for the poor example and about `SignIn` i gave the example how to use it above.
What i meant by runs asynchronously is that function natively support await without explicitly write `async`, even though after thinking about it i dont think the benefit is worth the work

@lustoykov hmm i thought about it but its not what i was looking for, thanks for the reply though